# Clone element X number of times using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone 50 times clone per click. How can I do it?

This is my script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>


<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>
```

Comment: Invoke the [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function inside a for loop

Comment: Please explain if you want ONE click to clone 50 times or ONE click clone ONCE but restrict clicking to a total of 50

Comment: @AlwaysHelping: no need for the word jquery in the title when it is in the tag. Also you now emphasised it is X TIMES per CLICK and not One Click X times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) jquery function to clone and `appendTo` function clone after the previously cloned element PER CLICK

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var e = $('p');
    if (e.length != 50) {
      $('p:first').clone().appendTo('#container');
    } else {
      console.log('You have reached limit of 50')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>


  <div id="container"></div>


  <button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
```

Comment: My comment is on the now removed loop. Also I do not know exactly what OP wants. It is still up in the air if `clone 50 times clone per click` is one click, clone 50 or one click clone once but restrict to 50 times

Comment: @mplungjan yes i agree to that - unless OP confirm otherwise. But per click i am guessing the limit is 50 and per click to reach that number.

Answer (score 0):

Clone ONCE and append ONCE!

NOTE: I read your requirements as "Clone 50 times per click"

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel click or make type="button"
    const clones = new Array(50);
    // Cloning ONCE and saving the output as string
    const html = $("p").map(function() { return this.cloneNode(true).outerHTML }).get().join("");
    // fill the array of HTML
    clones.fill(html)
    $("body").append(clones.join("")); // append ONCE
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>


<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>
```

To clone per click you can use a template

Note I put the counter on the button

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel click or make type="button"
    let times = +$(this).data("times"); // get a counter
    if (times > 5) return
    const html = $("template").contents().clone(true);
    $("body").append(html); // append ONCE
    $(this).data("times",++times);
  }).click()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</template>

<button data-times="1">Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>
```

Comment: The OP wanted per click clone not one click clone 50 ;)

Comment: That is your interpretation of `50 times clone per click`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I added a per click version